# How to select from a scroll select box

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to try and select from a strange scroll select box (picture below). I'm trying to use the Select option as I do with dropdowns, but that doesn't seem to be the answer here.

```
#I've tried finding the path to the element like this, trying to got the option I wanted.
profession = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ucLicenseLookup_ctl03_lbMultipleCredentialTypePrefix"]/option[28]'))
profession.select_by_value("Pharmacy")
#and I've tried using this.
profession = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ucLicenseLookup_ctl03_lbMultipleCredentialTypePrefix"]'))
profession.select_by_value("Pharmacy")
#Both of which fail to find the item I'm going for.enter image description here
```

[image: This is what the box I need to select from looks like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ucLicenseLookup_ctl03_lbMultipleCredentialTypePrefix']/option)[28]").click()
```

Comment: I know--it just won't me select it yet. I need to wait another few minutes.